# What does Momentum in name or variable scope of a Faster RCNN variable means?

Tags: python, python-2.7, object-detection, tensorflow

Printed below lines from tf.get_collection()

```
Tensor("conv3_1/weights/Momentum/read:0", shape=(3, 3, 128, 256), dtype=float32)
Tensor("conv3_1/biases/Momentum/read:0", shape=(256,), dtype=float32)
Tensor("conv3_2/weights/Momentum/read:0", shape=(3, 3, 256, 256), dtype=float32)
Tensor("conv3_2/biases/Momentum/read:0", shape=(256,), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Momentum" is the default name for the slots that the `MomentumOptimizer` allocates.

Slots are nothing but a set of additional variables (not trainable) associated with the variables to train (the model).

Once you know the slots names, you can ask the optimizer for the variable it created (filtering tf.get_collection() and looking for "Momentum" in var.name): you can then use them to debug the training algorithm, do stats about the slots, ...

References:

Slots description: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/97af82d5327e2e0142d8c572279b5282b7b17d92/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py#L235

Name "Momentum": https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/97af82d5327e2e0142d8c572279b5282b7b17d92/tensorflow/python/training/momentum.py#L52